# ¿Existe alguna palabra para describir a alguien que ignora a propósito?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

¿Qué palabra puede usarse para describir a alguien que ignora a propósito?

La primera palabra que me viene a la mente es *indiferencia*, pero no es indiferencia: *indiferencia* es no mostrar una actitud positiva o negativa hacia una persona o cosa, cuando ignorar a propósito en realidad muestra una actitud negativa.

¿Existe alguna palabra que se ajuste bien a esta situación?

Comment: Sería muy raro que alguien ignorase cosas solo porque sí. Creo que alguien ignora cosas _puntales_ debido a un cierto propósito o una cierta actitud, y entonces recibe un adjetivo (a veces quizá subjetivo) en base a lo que intenta, consigue o muestra con esa actitud o acto de ignorar a propósito. Dependiendo del ámbito (por ejemplo,política) le podrías llamar ideólogo, fanático, inconsciente, hipócrita... En otros contextos podría ser distante, desconectado de la realidad, cerrado, absorto...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sugiero ***desdeñar***. Dado que tenemos la palabra [**desdén**](https://dle.rae.es/desd%C3%A9n?m=form) (*de [desdeño](https://dle.rae.es/desde%C3%B1o?m=form)*) que significa:

> 1. m. Indiferencia y despego que denotan menosprecio.

Podemos tirar del hilo y utilizar la acción que lo representa:

> [**desdeñar**](https://dle.rae.es/desde%C3%B1ar?m=form)
>   *Del lat. dedignāre.*
>
> 1. tr. Tratar con desdén a alguien o algo.
>   2. prnl. p. us. Tener a menos el hacer o decir algo, juzgándolo por indecoroso.

Y la persona que así opera sería un [***desdeñoso***](https://dle.rae.es/?w=desde%C3%B1oso).

Me gusta porque en cierta medida se contrapone etimológicamente a *indignar*, que incorpora un sentimiento fuerte, mientras que el desdeño incorpora tanto el menosprecio como la ignoración de algo o alguien.

Answer (score 5):

Existe, la palabra es *[ignorar](https://dle.rae.es/?w=ignorar)* :)

Cuando se refiere a una persona, siempre es algo intencional:

> **2**. tr. No hacer caso de algo o de alguien, o tratarlos como si no merecieran atención. *Me duele que me ignore. Ignora sus comentarios.*

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez funcione la voz *contumaz*.

> contumaz
>
> 1. adj. Rebelde, porfiado y tenaz en mantener un error

Si consideramos que el error es desconocer o ignorar algo a propósito.

Comment: Un verbo que puede funcionar: DESENTENDERSE - prnl. Fingir que no se entiende algo, afectar ignorancia

Answer (score 0):

despreciar
Aprende a pronunciar
verbo transitivo
1.Considerar [una persona] que otra es indigna de su aprecio y trato, y demostrarlo rechazándola.
"lo despreciaron por cobarde"
2.Considerar que algo no merece aprecio o atención.
"despreciaba los esquemas archisabidos"

Es la palabra que se me ocurre, ya que es intencionadamente, sin embargo considero que a nadie le gustaría ser despreciado o ignorado en mi opinión ni en base a una actitud, juicio fama o personalidad. Porque igualmente ya no estaría considerado desprecio sino prejuicio, es decir, puede suponer una actitud pasivo-agresiva. En vez de decir lo que se piensa o siente se tiende  a ignorar.